# "Invalid argument: : Invalid to header" error in Google scripts using GmailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I keep getting "Invalid argument: : Invalid to header" on the following line in my google scripts code:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {from: 'first.last@gmail.com',cc: 'michelle@gmail.com,barack@gmail.com', htmlBody: message});
```

I am sending emails based on info from a google sheets doc. What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "from:" advanced parameter in the documentation. You cannot send a mail on behalf of someone else. This script will need to be run from their account if you want to the mail sent from them.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: Oops, I was looking at mailapp. Soz OP.